# How to Mongoose promise loop limit to only few times?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, promise

I'm writing a webshop in Node with Express and Mongoose. When a user buys a product (e.g. quanitity=5), the `postCheckout` Controller should check if there are enough items and then change the attribute "userId" to the user's id (`req.userId`) for 5 items. My current code changes the userId for all of the items, because I don't know how to limit the loop to 5 inside the promise.

```
exports.postCheckout = (req, res, next) => {
    const productId = req.body.productId;
    const quanitity = req.body.number;

    Item.find({productId: productId, userId: null})
        .then(async (items) => {
            if (items.length >= quanitity) {
                await Promise.all(items.map(async (item) => {
                    await item.update({userId: req.userId});
                }));
            }

            res.redirect('/orders');
        }).catch(err => { return next(err) });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways that you could go about doing this, but I think the simplest would be to slice your `items` array to the size you want before mapping over the items. Example is below (with slightly cleaned up async/await syntax).

```js
await Promise.all(items.slice(0, quantity).map(async (item) => {
    return item.update({userId: req.userId});
}));
```

Comment: Actually I just realized that it'd probably be cleaner to limit the query, so you never get more than enough responses in your `Item.find()`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already know how many items you are interested in, instead of querying the database for *all* the items, you can limit the result to only return the number of items you are interested in using `.limit(quantity)`, eg

```
exports.postCheckout = (req, res, next) => {
    const productId = req.body.productId;
    const quanitity = req.body.number;

    Item.find({productId: productId, userId: null})
        .limit(quantity) // <--- add this here
        .then(async (items) => {
            if (items.length >= quanitity) {
                await Promise.all(items.map(async (item) => {
                    await item.update({userId: req.userId});
                }));
            }

            res.redirect('/orders');
        }).catch(err => { return next(err) });
};
```

This way not all elements are pulled into memory, and you only ever update just the right number of items.